# C# Control Function Load order

Tags: c#, function

I am trying to have a dropdownlist set a temporary variable in the ViewState: `ViewState["TempProductVariantId"]`. Once it is set and the page reloads, I want to use that variable inside a function. After that function is complete the `ViewState["TempProductVariantId"]` is set to 0. My issue is I need to know what order the default functions load in the control. Ie. `Page_Load, OnPreRender, SelectedIndexChange, etc...`

**DropDownList SelectedIndexChange**

```
protected void ArtistArtwork_SelectedIndexChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;
    TempProductVariantId = int.Parse(ddl.SelectedValue);
}
```

**Page Load**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateAttributeControls();
    TempProductVariantId = 0;    
}
```

The problem with this is it work's literally every other time I change the selected index on the DropDownList.

So again I want to set it, use it, discard it. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You're interested in the ASP.NET Page Lifecycle - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: @MikeChristensen didn't see your comment as i was posting my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asp.net page lifecycle overview can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx but basically its Page_init -> Viewstate loaded -> Page_Load -> Events Fire -> Page_PreRender -> ViewState Saved -> Page_Render. Another trick you can use is to only initialize state variables on initial load by checking Page.IsPostBack (true on subsequent loads of the page)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @GaryS Now, When `ArtistArtwork_SelectedIndexChange` is fired does it restart the lifecycle?

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). Specifically look at the Control Events. To answer your specific example though, ArtistArtwork_SelectedIndexChange is running after Page_Load.